# Python can't import module with underscore on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I downloaded and installed flatten_json module in Python for Windows and it worked fine but when attempting to use it on an Ubuntu machine it says module not found. I know it is installed but cannot it get it to load. Can anyone help?

Comment: probably you have more than one python, e.g. python2 (the default one, works with `python` and `pip`) and python3 (works with `pip3` and `python3`) and you installed it for a different one than the one you use. Although I see it has only py3 wheel - maybe you have more than one python3 installation.

Comment: first check `python -V` and `pip -V` - maybe they uses different versions. And then you can use directly `python -m pip install ...` to install module with python which you use to run code.

Answer (score 0):

Is not very detailed what is going on, so I'm going to make some assumptions. I'm going to assume that the package is correctly installed in Ubuntu and you only have problems to import the module.

There is an [import problem](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten/issues/65) with 0.1.8 version. You should install the previous one that work fine. I'm going to also assume that you are using python 3. If not, replace pip3 with pip.

First uninstall the current version:

```
pip3 uninstall flatten_json
```

Second install the last working version:

```
pip3 install flatten_json==0.1.7
```

Then try again.

Comment: It worked! I Googled and Googled but didn't see that! Thank you for explaining! I will know where to look next time and sorry for not providing more details in the original post.